# Python venv works explicitly with python3.6, but not with python3.8

Tags: 18.04, python, python3, virtualenv

## #2 Edit - Solution:

so I found something that fixed it : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63207387/12291295

if you are getting afterwards a

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'

error, try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62831268/12291295

---

I'm trying to create a venv with `python3 -m venv env` or `python3.8 -m venv venv` and I get an error saying :

```
Error: Command '['<some_prior_path>/env/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

same with python3.8 just `<some_prior_path>/env/bin/python**3.8**`

but if I try `python3.6 -m venv env` it just executes as planned and then I can activate the venv.

#### Ubuntu Version

```
Release:    18.04
```

#### Python Version:

```
python3 -V 

Python 3.8.0
```

#### Things I've tried:

taken from : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62815398/12291295

```
sudo apt install python3.8 python3.8-venv
```

&

```
apt install python3.8 python3.8-venv python3-venv
```

returns that everything is installed & updated.

```
pip install --user virtualenv
```

returns :

```
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (20.0.31)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from virtualenv) (3.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs<2,>=1.4.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from virtualenv) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from virtualenv) (0.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-resources>=1.0; python_version < "3.7" in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from virtualenv) (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.9.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from virtualenv) (1.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata<2,>=0.12; python_version < "3.8" in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from virtualenv) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.4; python_version < "3.8" in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from importlib-resources>=1.0; python_version < "3.7"->virtualenv) (3.2.0)
```

and I think the problems lies here, I don't know how to make it to work with every python3 version, I mean why it's not located at `/usr/bin/python3`?

## Edit

it seems like pip installs on default to python3.6 version, and when I try

```
python3.8 -m pip install pip
```

I Get:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.8: No module named pip
```